# Perceptron exercise

Tags: machine-learning

I wonder how to find a solution to the following questions:

> Q: Design a two-input perceptron that implements the boolean function A ∧¬ B?
>
> Q: Design a two-layer network of perceptrons that implements A XOR B.
>
> Q: If it's possible to design one-layer perceptron that implements A XOR B?

What is the general approach to solve the exercise. The asnwer can be found in [solutions](http://ssdi.di.fct.unl.pt/scl/docs/exercises/soultion6.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is the back-propagation algorithm, but for simple cases like yours you can work out the right weights by searching through a small subset of the possible values and come up with a rough approximation of the best weights.